# “If you don’t know which book you can buy, we can advise you.”

Tags: relative-clauses, relative-pronouns

> If you don’t know which book you can buy, we can advise you.

In this sentence, is "which book you can buy" a defining relative clause introduced by the subordinator "which" as a relative determiner?

Comment: Your sentence suggests that there are books one cannot buy.  If you want to describe a situation where the person doesn't know which book to *choose*, it would be "If you don't know which book *to buy*, we can advise you."

Comment: @TimR The grammar question is the same regardless of the choice of verb.

Comment: @Barmar: I know, but when a canned sentence seems a bit suspect, I prefer to point it out.

Answer (score 1):

No. If it were an integrated relative clause, after all, it would be missing an antecedent.

Instead, this is a subordinate interrogative clause, sometimes called an "indirect question." Effectively, it's the subordinate-clause version of "Which book can you buy?"

Comment: Thank you for your answer!!